# CakePhp não redireciona no servidor Online

Tags: php, cakephp, redirecionamento

Bom dia!

Estou utilizando o framework cakephp, porém estou com um problema sem solução até o momento...
Tenho um controller de login, comentei todo o código de login e deixei apenas o trexo

> $this->redirect( array('controller' => 'nomedocontorller', 'action' => 'home') );

No localhost esse comando funciona normalmente, consigo direcionar a url, porém, quando coloco no servidor online simplesmente recebo uma página em branco e nenhuma mensagem de erro.

Já verifiquei espaços nos arquivos Index, routes, Controller e View, mas não tem espaços antes da tag de abertura do php
Já tentei abrir o php apenas com

> `<?`

Já subi um novo framework cakePHP para o servidor para testar se o problema estava oculto em algum dos arquivos, mas msm com os arquivos padrões do cakephp continuou não direcionando.
Já liberei o modo debug para printar os erros, mas msm assim não é reportado nenhum erro, nem visualmente nem no logo de erros.

Comment: Bom, você já falou que verificou espaços em branco, porém, a maioria dos problemas relacionados ou parecidos com o seu, acusam esse problema.  Espero que esse link te ajude: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16130309/cakephp-redirect-not-workin

Comment: Notei também que as sessões flash não estão sendo geradas...

Comment: @RafaelWithoeft Obrigado por comentar, eu já li esse link e executei aqueles passos da pergunta "fixa", porém, mesmo assim não corrigiu.

Comment: Verificou as permissões das pastas? (Provavelmente a documentação deve prover quais pastas precisão de permissões e qual o nível)...

Comment: @RafaelWithoeft tudo está com permissão total (777)...
Se o problema fosse permissão  provavelmente eu não conseguiria acessar via url, correto?

Comment: Acredito que acessaria normalmente, pois os arquivos por padrão tem permissão de leitura... etc, comentei das permissões pq, utilizo Yii2, e são necessárias permissões em algumas pastas e quando coloquei pela primeira vez no servidor a aplicação não funcionou como deveria, algumas páginas não carregaram (não lembro exatamente o que não funcionou, faz um bom tempo isso...), fui olhando e percebi as permissões que estavam erradas... Além de ter lido algum relato relacionado ao seu caso, de permissões em algum arquivo, `Auth` se não me engano. Claro que posso estar enganado quanto a isso.

Comment: @RafaelWithoeft Liberei as permissões novamente, mas mesmo assim não adiantou, realmente já não sei mais o que fazer, a única coisa que ainda não fiz é reabrir todos os arquivos codificando com UTF-8, mas tem muito arquivo esse projeto, se for fazer isso literalmente com todos estou ferrado. 

Agradeço pela ajuda @RafaelWithoeft!

Answer (score 1):

Depois de 3 dias brigando e algumas noites "sem dormir",confesso que já estava  desanimado.

Hoje acordei inspirado a resolver esse problema e comecei a fazer buscas no projeto por tags php que tinham espaços vazios antes ou depois da abertura/fechamento.

Para a minha felicidade, encontrei em torno de 5 arquivos que tinham esse problema, após corrigir esses arquivos parece que o direcionamento e sessão voltaram a funcionar.

Solução:
Procurar por tags php que foram abertas/fechadas antes ou depois das tags 
Exemplo:

```
(quebra de linha ou espaço)
<?php
```

ou

```
?>
(quebra de linha ou espaço)
```

Após remover essas ocorrências, parece que tudo voltou ao normal.
Tive mais um problema de direcionamento, mas creio que esse é um pouco diferente.

Obrigado pela ajuda de todos!

Answer (score 0):

Esse problema é comum quando há headers enviados. No lugar do redirect, tente utilizar o seguinte e veja qual erro é retornado:

```
<?php header( 'Location: http://www.google.com/' ) ; ?>
```

Quando utilizar o redirect, é boa prática adicioná-la ao return:

```
return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
```

Na sua action, adicione o debug abaixo e observe qual o retorno:

```
if (headers_sent($file, $line)) {
    exit("headers were already sent in file: {$file}, line number: {$line}");
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Marcelo.

Já havia visto algo parecido com o que você postou, tentei mas não consegui muita coisa.
Hoje de manhã consegui resolver, vou postar a solução que encontrei.
Mas, mesmo assim, Obrigado!